# Netbeans mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-7

Using netbeans and mysql i've created a table that i want the user to ba able to add data to it using java. Could someone give an example how to add for example a new client name to a table name client with field name.

This puts it automatically but i need the user to add the name to the table

```
  public static void insertClients() throws SQLException {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    }  catch (Exception E) {
        System.err.println("Unable to load driver.");
        E.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection(
                         "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/clients","root","pass");
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        String newClient = "insert into client values(John);";
        statement.executeUpdate(newName);
        System.out.println("Client added");
        con.commit();
        con.close();
```

Comment: You need quotes around your name and should name the column you insert into. But better use *prepared statements*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can follow the official [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) on how to use Prepared Statements for inserting data into tables.

It hardly will take you an hour to try out the examples given there.

Hope it helps.